# Novel about the future of communication, everything becoming shorter and shorter

Tags: identification-request

Years ago, roaming around in a library, I stumbled across a short novel about the future of communication. I think that it was written in the 70s.

Starting from the first appearance of the Reader's Digest, the author imagined the future of literature was described as progressive condensation of information. Forced by the more and more pronounced frenzy of daily life, people lacked time and looked for shorter and shorter news, literature and personal conversations.

I'd love to read again this novel but I forgot title and author. It was a short (and a bit gloomy) story. It was translated into Italian.

Comment: Welcome to Literature! Anything else you can remember about this story? Did you read it in English? Was it translated?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I do not remember much. It was a short (and a bit gloomy) story. It was translated into Italian.